# Изменения пользователя у домена

Tags: modx

Всем привет, решил у домена изменить пользователя в Isp Manager, перенес папку другому пользователю, удалил старого пользователя. Но после после стало выдавать ошибку 500, логи приложил. В чем может быть проблема?

```
[Wed Apr 10 11:12:46.183885 2019] [:error] [pid 12219] [client 141.8.132.2:48194] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'EvolutionCMS\\Exceptions\\ContainerException' with message 'EvolutionCMS\\Interfaces\\DatabaseInterface contains circular reference' in /var/www/User/data/www/site.com/manager/includes/src/Core.php:220\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/User/data/www/site.com/manager/includes/src/Core.php(190): EvolutionCMS\\Core->createService('EvolutionCMS\\\\In...')\n#1 /var/www/User/data/www/site.com/manager/includes/src/Core.php(298): EvolutionCMS\\Core->getService('EvolutionCMS\\\\In...')\n#2 /var/www/User/data/www/site.com/manager/includes/src/Core.php(3730): EvolutionCMS\\Core->getDatabase()\n#3 /var/www/User/data/www/site.com/manager/includes/src/Core.php(6598): EvolutionCMS\\Core->logEvent(0, 3, '<b>Undefined in...', 'Parser -       ...')\n#4 /var/www/User/data/www/site.com/manager/includes/src/Core.php(6413): EvolutionCMS\\Core->messageQuit('PHP Parse Error', '', true, 2, '/var/www/User...', '            $th...', 'mysqli::mysqli(...', 75)\n#5 [internal function] in /var/www/User/data/www/site.com/manager/includes/src/Core.php on line 220
```

Comment: владелец/группа файлов и папок меняли тоже? Возможно надо изменить рекурсивно на нового пользователя

Comment: Да, полностью все изменил, но ошибка осталась. Также пишет какие то проблемы с БД, судя по логам, но в БД я нормально захожу.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос, проблема была с пользователем в БД.